# How to stop scheduled flow in corda?

Tags: corda

I have scheduled a flow using nextScheduledActivity(). After once the flow is initiated, I want to stop the scheduled flow. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways in which it can be stopped:

1. Consume the incoming state. Once state is consumed, it stops.
2. Specify a time in past in nextScheduledActivity() based on an exit condition - this disables any further scheduling.
3. return null from nextScheduledActivity() based on an exit condition